# Invite friends with new Facebook api

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, showdialog

I've just updated Facebook framework and old code for invite friends does't work(Now there is no Facebook class object.). I used the following code:

```
     NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"1", @"frictionless",
     @"My message", @"message",
     @"Notification", @"notification_text",nil];
     [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Is it possible to show the same dialog on the latest framework?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157784/can-we-invite-people-to-use-our-app-or-send-friend-request-from-the-app-via-face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. The sample iOS game, Friend Smash (https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-friend-smash), uses this technique. The equivalent code is here:

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-friend-smash/blob/master/friendsmash/friendSmasher/Game/GameController_FacebookIntegration.cpp#L365

Comment: Thanks I found solution. Just use deprecated Facebook object. I found it in the official Facebook guide.

Comment: Yeah, the 3.0 SDK is intended to be backwardly compatible (although there will sometimes be better ways to do things)